# WCF deserialization trying to convert xml parameter to object when I just want the string

Tags: c#, wcf, deserialization

I am writing a WCF service stub to 'mimic' an existing VB6 service that exists. The stub needs to accept a single parameter which is a string, perform some logic and return a string.

The issue I am having is given the following method on the service contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "lookup")]
string LookupItem(string requestXml);
```

When I post a message in fiddler I get the error

> The server encountered an error
>   processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Unable to deserialize XML
>   body with root name 'XmlRoot' and
>   root namespace '' (for operation
>   'LookupItem' and contract
>   ('IServiceStub', 
>   'http://tempuri.org/')) using
>   DataContractSerializer. Ensure that
>   the type corresponding to the XML is
>   added to the known types collection of
>   the service.'.

Is WCF trying to deserialize my XML into an object, even though I don't want it to? The string is being sent as text/xml because the service it's mimicking has to receive the POST as text/xml. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overcame this with the following:

```
public Stream LookupItem(Message requestXml)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
        string responseXml = "<whatever />";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseXml ));
    }
```